# Would it be a bad idea to not book hotels ahead in Thailand?

Tags: hotels, thailand, chiang-mai, phi-phi

I am travelling to Thailand this month in the shoulder season. I will be going to Chiang Mai, Koh Phi Phi and Koh Lanta.

I intentionally planned a loose itinerary and only booked my first few nights accommodation in Chiang Mai after I land. I had the idea of walking around finding suitable hotels when I reached my destination, not booking ahead (I know it's a different place but I visited Bali last year and found this approach was easier and cheaper).

Would this approach be ok? Or would it be difficult?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to book in advance?

Comment: @stephanmg I don't know how long I'm going to stay in each place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow traveller and often backpacker, I would advise you to do so in most places, but I don't know how long are you staying in Thailand. Visas can go from 2 weeks to 3 months, so if you intend to stay only 2 weeks then I would recommend to plan ahead so that you won't lose any precious time  searching for a place to sleep or even changing accommodations (if you stay somewhere on the run and you end up not liking the place).

My personal approach is to not plan ahead and book places as we travel, 1 or 2 days before and only for 1 or 2 nights (so that if I don't like the place, I can change it without loosing booking costs) and extend the stay for as much as I like.

Also, if you end up staying at hostels ( for the simple fact that you meet alot of travellers and can get good travel tips and booking & restaurants recommendations) you should know that many hostel brands give discounts if you book with them in the next destinations (if there is one).
Good luck and safe travels!